# How do I create one trigger that updates DateModified on any table that updates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am creating a trigger on every table so that the column DateModified is updated when a row updates. Is there a way to create one trigger that updates DateModified on any table that updates? DateModified and DateCreated are on ever table in my database.

Thanks!!

Comment: I would never do such a thing, you are going to double the time for each transaction. And based in my previous experience, these columns will not help you on the road to auditing and versioning. If you would like to dig it, you use traces on every DML activity and then apply those traces somewhere else. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I do not have allot of traffic at the moment so if I double my transaction time it will not kill performance. I need a today solution but will start researching DML for phase two. 

Any suggestions for phase one trigger are appreciated.

Comment: Don't think there's built-in syntax to support this kind of a trigger template. The solution (or workaround, depending on how you see it) would likely need to involve querying metadata for the table list and generating triggers in a cursor using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method, without manually querying metadata tables:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'CREATE TRIGGER ... ON ''?'' AFTER ...'
```